# How to fix infinite object nesting or set a max depth level with AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, automapper, circular-reference

I am working on a project where I need to map a list of a specific object to another list. You can find the objects below. I need to serialize the list into a JSON string, but it throws the next error:

```
System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32.'
```

The objects (cutted):

```
    class Class1
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; } = new List<Product>();
    }

    class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Class1 Class1 { get; set; }
    }

    class Class1Model
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }

    class ProductModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Class1Model Class1 { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my mapperprofile:

```
public class MyMapper : Profile
{
    public MyMapper()
    {
        CreateMap<Class1, Class1Model>().MaxDepth(2);
        CreateMap<Product, ProductModel>().MaxDepth(2);
    }
}
```

When debugging, my mapped list shows infinite nested objects. For example:

```
Class1Model
   --> Products, each Product 
        --> Class1Model
            --> Products, each Product
                 --> Class1Model
                    --> repeating....
```

The `MaxDepth` configuration in my `MapperProfile` doesn't fix this issue. I want a real max depth of for example 2, so that my `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` doesn't break. We deliberately don't want to use NewtonSoft JSON.

Comment: do you use the latest version 5.0.x of System.Text.Json?

Comment: @magicandre1981 nope, we use 4.7.2

Comment: use latest [5.0.1 package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json/5.0.1)

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks we've tried it. But we can't figure out how to configure a custom depth amount. So for example, we DO want it to be nested, but to a certain amount of levels. Not infinitely. Is this possible? And if so, is it configurable through System.Text.Json or through AutoMapper? And how?

Comment: version 5 added circular-reference suport, but I still use the old NewtonSoft JSON. Play a bit with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded my `System.Text.Json` to v5.0.1.

I created a JsonSerializerOptions object:

```
 var settings = new JsonSerializerOptions
 {
     ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve
 };
```

Serializing:

```
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(class1s, options: settings);
```

When serializing the object into a JSON string, the string is built in this way:

```
var deserializedJson = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<Class1Model>>(json, options: settings);

{"$id":"1","$values":[{"$id":"2","Name":"t","Products":{"$id":"3","$values":[{"$id":"4","Name":"p","Class1":{"$id":"5","Name":"t","Products":{"$id":"6","$values":[{"$ref":"4"}]}}}]}}]}
```

Somehow, the `$id`, `$values`, and `$ref` tags remember how to build up the object in its original structure when deserializing as it was before serializing it into a JSON string.

This was the fix.

Comment: nice to hear that you got it working with the last version of the System.Text.Json lib